# This API project is not authorized to use this API - using geocode in R

Tags: r, geocode

I've been looking all the answers to this same question, but the solutions seem to be too old or not working...

I am using geocode from the ggmap library in R, I am using it to transform 100,000 addresses to a latitude and longitude...

Everything was working fine for 25,000 and suddenly I started getting the message
"This API project is not authorized to use this API" and now I'm unable to do anything anymore.

I enabled the geocoding API and the google cloud APIs in the google cloud platform..
I also changed the API key, it first said my key expired but after a while it started saying "This API project is not authorized to use this API" again..

As an additional note, my billing method is enabled and working fine

Why do you think this is happening? How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

well, after an hour or so it seems that it started working again... I assume considering that enabling the geocoding API was the only actual action I did and changing the API key, the only conclusion is that after you do that it's important to wait until all the changes are propagated or something.